# How to fix "Not Recognized As an Internal or External Command" when calling lrelease in PySide2 virtual environment?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm working on this [template project for PySide2](https://github.com/JackLilhammers/pyside2-boilerplate).
As you can read in the [documentation](https://github.com/JackLilhammers/pyside2-boilerplate#resources-and-translations), the user has to manually add the path to `lrelease.exe` either to `PATH` or to a new environmental variable named `LRELEASE_BIN`.

> ### Resources and translations
>
> In order to ease the development process,
> the Qt Creator project app.pro is provided. You can open it to edit
> the UI files or to manage resources. Translations can be edited using
> Qt Linguist, part of the Qt SDK. In order to build the translations,
> you will need to have the lrelease command on your PATH or set its
> full path to the LRELEASE_BIN environment variable. UI files,
> translations and resources can be built like this:
>
> ```
> python setup.py build_res
> ```

As part of the changes I'm making to my fork, I'd like to use `lrelease` from the `PySide2` package installed inside the virtual environment.
It would avoid having to install Qt and make all the dependencies self contained.
The problem is that when I try to launch `python.exe .\setup.py build_res` with the local path to `lrelease.exe`

```
lrelease = ".venv/Lib/site-packages/PySide2/lrelease.exe"
check_call([lrelease, "app.pro"])
```

I get the following error:

```
"C:/Users/my_user/path_to_my_project/.venv/Lib/site-packages/PySide2/lrelease-pro.exe" Not Recognized As an Internal or External Command
```

and

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['.venv/Lib/site-packages/PySide2/lrelease.exe', 'app.pro']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

**Is there a way to rely on the `lrelease` executable installed by pip?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the error message, the `lrelease.exe` program that you launch appears to execute `lrelease-pro.exe`, which doesn't exist in the directory `.venv/Lib/site-packages/PySide2/`. I can confirm that I've got no such program myself in a virtual environment containing PySide2 5.15.2 on Windows, only `lrelease.exe`:

```
$ find .venv/ -name "*lrelease*"
.venv/Lib/site-packages/PySide2/lrelease.exe
```

Given that `lrelease.exe` is in `.venv/Lib` and not `.venv/Scripts`, it feels like it is not provided by PySide2 with the intention to be used by the user, contrary to `pyside2-lupdate.exe` which is in `.venv/Scripts`. On Linux, `lrelease` isn't even provided in `.venv/lib`, it is completely absent.

So I'd wager that no, it is not currently supported to use the `lrelease.exe` executable installed by `pip` as part of PySide2. Potential alternatives:

- On the off-chance that `lrelease.exe` is also provided by Qt Creator, it is possible to [install Qt Creator alone](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers), rather than together with the full Qt SDK, which is very large.
- Searching for "lrelease" on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=lrelease) yields *distutils-ui* and *setup_qt* which sound like they may provide an `lrelease` executable.

Comment: I'm trying `setup_qt`. I'll let you know if it solves the issue. In the meantime thank you

Comment: At the moment it seems that the only solution is to use the *lrelease.exe* binary installed with Qt. It's not a big deal since I develop also with standard Qt, but it makes PySide and PyQt incomplete...

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, hoping that someone finds a way in the future :)